# Pad multiple torch tensor over the last dim

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have multiple torch tensors with the following shapes

```
x1 = torch.Size([1, 512, 177])
x2 = torch.Size([1, 512, 250])
x3 = torch.Size([1, 512, 313])
```

How I can pad all these tensors by 0 over the last dimension, to have a unique shape like ([1, 512, 350]).

What I tried to do is to convert them into NumPy arrays and use these two lines of code:

```
if len(x1) < 350:
            ff = np.pad(f, [(0, self.max_len - f.shape[0]), ], mode='constant')
            f = ff
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't affect the last dim and still, the shapes are not equal.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = F.pad(x, (0, self.max_len - x.size(2)), "constant", 0)
```